# Metric with open singletons

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

The analysis textbook we use in class states

> If $(X,d)$ is a metric space $\{a_0\}$, $a_0\in X$, is not open, if $X\neq\{a_0\}.$

This is clearly wrong taking the discrete metric as a counterexample. I am wondering, is there any other metric on any set (which is not equivalent to the discrete metric) which has at least one open singleton? Or are all singletons in a metric space necessarily open if one singleton is open and hence the metric equivalent to the discrete metric?

Edit: José has given a nice example but I am still wondering what happens if one puts the additonal constraint on $X$ of being connected. Does in this case $d$ have to be equivalent to the discrete metric?

Comment: Singletons in a metric space are closed sets. So $\{p\}$ cannot be open in the connected metric space $X$ unless $\{p\}=X.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ endowed with the usual metric. This space has one and only one open singleton, which is $\{2\}$.

Comment: Excellent example, didn't think of that! What if $X$ has to be connected?

Comment: If $X$ is connected and its metric is the discrete metric, then $X$ consists of a single point.